# Can I make my class iterable only to use one of its iterable attributes?

Tags: python, iterable

As I am making a genetic algorithm, I have a `Individu` class:

```
class Individu:
  genotype: List[int]
  code: List[int]
  phenotype: List[List[Client]]
  fitness: float
```

Most of the time only the attribute `genotype` is used in the program (for crossing over parents or computing the fitness).

Now, instead of always writing `p1.genotype[]` when I need to use it, could I make `Individu` iterable so that I can write `p1[]` instead or is it a bad idea?

I feel like it would make my program cleaner for me but at the same time could be confusing for others or 'break' some kind of programming best practice.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're doing with `foo.bar[]` but it's reasonable to implement e.g. the [sequence ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) to make your class easier to use.

Comment: I think your usecase, classname, documentation should clarify the issue. `range` is a class, that is iterable, and has other attributes like `start`, `stop` etc. So whether or not it's a good idea, depends on what is your intent for the object.

Comment: I made an edit with my usecase, I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be talking about indexing, not iteration per se. Indexing is handled by the `__getitem__` method while iteration is handled by `__iter__`/`iter`. You could just define these methods for your class to forward the work to the `genotype` attribute:

```
def __getitem__(self, key): return self.genotype[key]
def __iter__(self): return iter(self.genotype)
```

Personally I wouldn't do it because this indirection is extra work, probably isn't everything you want to forward to the `genotype` attribute, and obscures where the iterable really is. But if it fits your use case, then go for it.